# Laravel move row data from table to another table using button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

Just to have an example. After I click the button it should move the row into another table in the database just like it is shown here and delete it afterwards. After I click the approve button the data row should transfer to another table in database. I really don't know how to start something like this in Laravel and I really can't find something related.

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q81n.png)

Here's my view.blade.php

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered tbl_pendingres" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th hidden>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Reservation Date</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($app as $resdata)
            <tr>
                <td hidden>{{$resdata->id}} </td>
                <td>{{$resdata->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$resdata->Name_item}}</td>
                <td>{{$resdata->dt_item}}</td>
                <td>{{$resdata->room_item}} </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="admin.reservations.store{{ $resdata->id}}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                            Accept
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        </button></a>
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        Cancel
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my reservation controller

```html
public function store($id)
{
    $first = Reservation::find($id); //this will select the row with the given id

    // now save the data in the variables;
    $ab = $first->name;
    $cd = $first->Name_item;
    $ef = $first->dt_item;
    $gh = $first->room_item;
    $ij = $first->ldate_item;

    $second = new AcceptedReservation();
    $second->a_name = $ab;
    $second->a_nitem = $cd;
    $second->a_ditem = $ef;
    $second->a_ritem = $gh;
    $second->a_ldateitem = $ij;
    $second->save();

    // then return to your view or whatever you want to do
    return view('admin.reservations.index')->with('message','Reservation Accepted');
}
```

Also when I clicking the button it always having error
Too few arguments to function

> App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReservationsController::store(), 0 passed in C:\laragon\www\ecmtech\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: in your route add /{id} and where you are setting the endpoint pass the id at the end

Comment: But it is a default function in laravel.

Comment: No it's not like that please do what I say and then ask

Comment: Your store function needs a parameter ```$id```, please have a look at your function ```public function store($id)``` .

Comment: Route::resource('reservations', ReservationsController::class);

Comment: Heres my route. What should i change?

Comment: yes this route will have ```Route::resource('reservations'/{id}, ReservationsController::class);```

Comment: There's a red in line I thinks it will not going to run.

Comment: Please check the ```Route Parameters``` in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: Okay thanks. How about my other problem do you have any idea on how to move data from table to another table?

Comment: @ECMTECH check my answer

Comment: Okay wait ill try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep the store function empty remove $id also .like this

```
public function store()
{
  // do nothing
}
```

Create a new function like this in the controller

```
     public function acceptReservation(Request $request, $id)
        {
    
        $first = Reservation::find($id); //this will select the row with the given id
    
        //now save the data in the variables;
        $ab = $first->name;
        $cd = $first->Name_item;
        $ef = $first->dt_item;
        $gh = $first->room_item;
        $ij = $first->ldate_item;
    
    
        $second = new AcceptedReservation();
        $second->a_name = $ab;
        $second->a_nitem = $cd;
        $second->a_ditem = $ef;
        $second->a_ritem = $gh;
        $second->a_ldateitem = $ij;
        $second->save();
     /// IF YOU NEED TO REMOVE 1st TABLE VALUE    
  $first->delete();

        //then return to your view or whatever you want to do
        return redirect()->route('admin.reservations.index')->with('message','Reservation Accepted');
    
        }
```

now DEFINE The ROUTE Like this

```
Route::post('reservation-accept/{id}', [ReservationsController::class,'acceptReservation'])->name('reservation.accept');
```

Now where you are adding the accept button add it call it like this

```
<form action="{{route('admin.reservation.accept',$resdata->id)}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Accept <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: It gives me error Route [reservation.accept] not defined.

Comment: clear your route cache and restart the server

Comment: How to clear it?

Comment: Run in command
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache

Comment: Then stop the php artisan serve and serve again

Comment: Same error. Please do help me.

Comment: @ECMTECH do you have added the route in web.php ?

Comment: Please add this in web.php just after the resource you have defined 
Route::post('reservation-accept/{id}', [ReservationsController::class,'acceptReservation'])->name('reservation.accept');

Comment: Yes this is what i add, Route::post('reservation-accept/{id}', [ReservationsController::class,'acceptReservation'])->name('reservation.accept');

Comment: Yes that is what i add.

Comment: @ECMTECH Do you have stopped the server and started again?

Comment: Yes. I have it already.

Comment: can edit your question and add the route web.php screenshot to it

Comment: Can i send u the file or my project? So that u can see it.

Comment: that will be better if you can

Comment: what is your email?

Comment: Or where should i send it?

Comment: i already send it. hope youll help me.

Comment: oh man you have a prefix admin. in your route group so the route name should be 
'admin.reservation.accept' and the csrf field you have remove should exists there. Other issues please fix by yourself

Comment: I works now. One last problem is Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

Comment: Please just last one

Comment: please remove 
 return view('admin.reservations.index')->with('message','Reservation Accepted');
and add 
return redirect()->route('admin.reservations.index')->with('message','Reservation Accepted');